# Redux-Thunk : Actions must be plain objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Redux thunk is not working for me, not sure why not. Before, everything worked. Now I'm trying to get redux-thunk to work, but it's just giving me

> Actions must be plain objects

My Code is fairly standard, I think:

**createStore**

```
import { createStore as reduxCreateStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reducers from './src/reducers';

import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

const createStore = () =>
  reduxCreateStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(reduxThunk));
export default createStore;
```

**Put store into Provider**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducer from "./src/reducers";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.store = createStore(reducer);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={this.store}>
        //...My App
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**Call Action from React Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import m from "mousetrap";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "./src/actions";

class Mousetrap extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() { //binding the action to mousetrap hotkeys here
    m.bind(["space"], () => this.props.nextDiv());
  }
  //...
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.auth,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Mousetrap);
```

**Action Creator:**

```
export const nextDiv = () => {
   return (dispatch, getState) => {
     dispatch({ type: NEXT_DIV });
  };
};
```

From what I've found online so far, it looks like most people get this error when there is something wrong in their action creator, i.e. when they don't return the function etc. - but I am doing this correctly, I believe?

I think maybe something goes wrong in this step:

```
import * as actions from "./src/actions";
//...
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Mousetrap);
```

Maybe I cannot import thunk action creators like this? Or maybe my binding the action is somehow not working with redux-thunk now? Sorry for asking this, I feel it's probably something trivial! Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: As a first observation, your `nextDiv` function does not _need_ to be a thunk as currently written.  It could simply be `const nextDiv = () => ({type: "NEXT_DIV"})`.  Second, I would suggest sticking a breakpoint in the code of the Redux `createStore` function in your browser's DevTools, and see what actual value is reaching `dispatch`.  Third, I'd strongly recommend [using our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) to set up the store instead of doing it by hand.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mark. I've been reading lots of your posts, really appreciate your work! I'm aware I don't need a thunk here, I just wanted to figure out where the problem lies so I simplified matters a bit. I'll check out the redux toolkot package, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're not using your `createStore` method, rather importing it from redux again. So the middleware is not added.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux"; <--
import reducer from "./src/reducers";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.store = createStore(reducer);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={this.store}>
        //...My App
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for spotting this! Can't believe it was so trivial! Thank you!!