# Actions must be plain objects error with redux-thunk on React SSR

Tags: reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering

I'm not sure which part I misconfigured.  I'm doing a comparison between these two:

```js
// actions.js
// this runs without a issue
export const someAction = (val) => {
  return {
    type: 'SOME_TYPE',
  }
}

// modifying the above to this gets the "actions must be plain objects" error message
export const someAction = (val) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    // console log here doesn't run
    return {
      type: 'SOME_TYPE',
    }
  }
}
```

The error message is as follows:

```sh
Unhandled rejection Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

So I checked my store

```js
// store.js
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import mainReducer from './reducers';

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

const store = (preloadedState) => createStore(
  mainReducer,
  preloadedState,
  applyMiddleware(
    thunkMiddleware,
    loggerMiddleware,
  ),
);

export default store;
```

Since I'm running React in a SSR environment, I am following the [redux documentation on server rendering](https://redux.js.org/recipes/server-rendering/#security-considerations) carefully.

I've noticed that useEffect doesn't get fired in SSR.  So I'm running dispatch in the function:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { someAction } from 'somewhere...';

const ThisPage = (props) => {
  const { dispatch, val } = props;
  dispatch(someAction(val));  // <-- here

  return (
    <>stuff</>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = () => {
  // some mapping
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ThisPage);
```

Can someone help me narrow down this issue?

```sh
// Versions:
react@16.13.0
react-redux@7.2.0
redux@4.0.5
redux-thunk@2.3.0
```

Comment: How are you calling someAction() method,Please mention.

Comment: @Ashish I've added my response in the question

Comment: You can not directly calling the action method if you return the function (as you did in second way) instead of object. for the second way you need to use mapDispatchToprops and pass it to connect hoc.

Comment: const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return {
  importFrameworkData: (data, tabEnable) => dispatch(api.someAction(data)),
 
 }
};

Comment: @Ashish hmm, actually, that wasn't it.  My method does the same thing.  It's equivalent to this, `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ThisPage);`. I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: So, how are you accessing  the that method?

Comment: Same way as before, `const ThisPage = (props) => {
  props.importFrameworkData('val');`

Comment: Ah, so it turned out I made a simple mistake, same as this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60459232/redux-thunk-actions-must-be-plain-objects?rq=1. It's working now.

Comment: Good to know, BTW what mistake you had doing?

Comment: @Ashish the mistake was in the loading of the store.  I needed to bring in the store from store.js but I was pulling in createStore from redux, `import { createStore } from 'redux'`, `const store = createStore(counterApp, preloadedState)`, as referenced in the documentation.